# JSF 2.0: how to save the view after redirect (target=blank)

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, target

Imagine I have the jsf form and the button to print report on form data. The button needs to open the data on the new page (**target=blank**), but **h:button** doesn't suit as I need to save the data just before the report page open. So, I use **h:commandButton** which makes the save action, and then redirects to the report page:

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="reportButton" action="#{polisBean.doReportPrint}"
                    target="_blank" id="reportListLink">
                    Print report
                </h:commandLink>

@ViewScoped
@Named
public class PolisBean
  ...
  public Object doReportPrint() {        
    if (canEdit() && this.submit() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return "printReport";
}
<navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>printReport</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/polises/reportList.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect include-view-params="true">
            <view-param>
                <name>id</name>
                <value>#{polis.id}</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
```

The entity is saved perfectly and the new page is open with the report. Good. But when I go back to the initial form page and try to save again - the view is expired and built by new (as this is not a postback request, this is a totally new request for JSF, because I just made the redirect from this page!). Although the redirect was done while opening second page, this doesn't prevent from loosing all view scoped bean data..

I tried the long-running **conversationScope** from CDI, but it throws the "ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped" exception when I turn back to the initial page...

Has anyone solved the problem? How can I do the form submit with the redirect (to new page) but not loose the initial data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found the workaround. Not very beautiful, but allows to work with redirects to "blank" pages:

The receipt is to do the refresh of the initial page just after the link was opened in new window (see **onclick**):

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="reportButton" action="#{polisBean.doReportPrint()}" onclick="window.setTimeout(refreshPage, 2000)"
                    target="_blank" id="reportListLink" >
                    print report
                </h:commandLink>
```

But that's not as simple as it seems to be, I cannot use the simple location.reload() or smth similar. In the **doReportPrint()** method I do the save operation and if the entity does not exist, it is created. As I use GET-parametrized request for my application, I will need to refresh page using the following address with **id** parameter:

```
/polises/polis.jsf?id=80
```

So, the the new jsf request needs to be done, not a simple JS refresh, which contains the id of newly created entity. So I use this approach:

In **doReportPrint** I save the newly created id to the session:

```
public Object doReportPrint() {        
    if (canEdit() && this.submit() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    context().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("justUpdatedPolisId", entity.getId());        
    return "printReport";
}
```

And the refresh of the initial page is done the following way:

```
public Object doRefresh() {
    Object justUpdatedPolisId = context().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("justUpdatedPolisId");
    if (justUpdatedPolisId != null) {
        entity.setId((Long)justUpdatedPolisId);
        context().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("justUpdatedPolisId");
        return "save";
    }
    // If for some reasons we have not found it - moving to polises table
    return "polises?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

**Save** outcome results in polis.jsf reopen (using faces-config navigation) and the id is attached from **entity.id** automatically

Another trick is how to call the JSF action from JS. I tried to imitate **h:commandLink** click (just copied the generated JS code for the link), but this didn't work, as the view is recreated and the same for bean and its properties, actions simply wasn't called. So I used the JS code for PrimeFaces **p:commandLink** and it worked great for me (dont' forget to set "update" to @none and "process" to @this):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function refreshPage() {
                        PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest('/KaskoCalculator/polises/polis.jsf',{formId:'polisForm',async:false,global:true,source:'polisForm:doRefresh',process:'polisForm:doRefresh',update:'@none'});
                        }
   </script>
```

So now the initial page is being refreshed in 2 seconds after the report being saved and opened in new windows. Too ugly and too burdensome, but it works for me. May be will help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. 
Using p:commandLink, or h:commandLink with target=_blank, the initial page backing bean data is gone after opening the new window.

The refresh will go back to the initial state of the page without ajax updates. but I need to keep the same state before clicking the print command.