# Elegant handling of attributes without a session bean

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm working on an application using JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 4, that consists of many tables that display elements and of course, the usual View/Edit/Delete options. After some SO browsing and Google search I've decided to post a question because the answers I found did not solve my problem.

Right now, and going straight to the point, my application is having issues when handling certain attributes that are stored in request beans and, on certain points, are lost due to successive requests.

For example, when I want to edit an object, the object is sent (f:propertyActionListener) to a request bean that displays the data on a form, then it is discarded as that request ends. When saving, a new object is created and the attributes on the form are setted to it and the item gets saved instead of updated, since it has no id (JPA + Hibernate).

I've investigated many options and this is what I've did so far and the results:

**f:param + h:link or h:commandLink:** With @ManagedProperty the param is null, and I can't find it on the Context to look it up through JNDI.

**f:setPropertyActionListener + h:commandLink + Request Bean:** Works... but I'm losing some data. The form that displays the data has some conditionally rendered fields and I can't hold that info, so the form is messed if the validation phase finds invalid data.

**f:viewParam + h:commandLink + View Scoped Bean:** Weird stuff here. This one doesn't directly work because the bean seems to get discarded before rendering the form, because the form is rendered with no information since the bean is clean.

**Using a session bean:** Works like a charm, but I don't want to make a session bean for every form just because I'm still learning things about the JSF lifecycle, I want to do it the proper way.

If I want to keep the Request session approach, is there a way to store a parameter (either an object or a plain string) and obtain later on a request bean?.

Dunno if this helps but I'm using a master page through ui:insert and ui:define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view scoped bean. It should work. The problems which you describe there suggests that you're binding it to JSTL tags or `id` or `binding` attributes. You should not do that on a view scoped bean. See also [`@ViewScoped` fails in tag handlers](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers). Another possible cause is that you're using CDI's `@Named` to manage the bean instead of JSF's `@ManagedBean`. That would also explain why `@ManagedProperty` doesn't work in one of your attempts as it also requires the bean to be managed by JSF's `@ManagedBean`.

As to the master-detail page approach, use a `<h:link>` with `<f:param>` in the table page to create view/edit links in the master page.

E.g. `user/list.xhtml`

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{userList.users}" var="user">
    <h:column>#{user.id}</h:column>
    <h:column>#{user.name}</h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:link value="Edit" outcome="edit">
            <f:param name="id" value="#{user.id}" />
        </h:link>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The bean can be just request scoped.

Then, in the defail page, which is in this case an edit page, use `<f:viewParam>` to convert, validate and set the `id` as `User`.

E.g. `user/edit.xhtml`

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{userEdit.user}"
        converter="#{userConverter}" converterMessage="Bad request. Unknown user."
        required="true" requiredMessage="Bad request. Please use a link from within the system." />
</f:metadata>

<h:messages />
<h:link value="Back to all users" outcome="users" />

<h:form id="user" rendered="#{not empty userEdit.user}">
    <h:inputText value="#{userEdit.user.name}" required="true" />
    ...

    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{userEdit.save}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Use a `@ViewScoped` bean to hold the data, service and action methods:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserEdit {

    private User user;

    @EJB
    private UserService service;

    public String save() {
        service.save(user);
        return "users";
    }

    // Getter+setter.
}
```

Comment: Even in this case, is `@ViewScoped` really a good solution? Though it takes a little more work, I've typically favored `@ConversationScoped` to avoid problems with back-button use, multiple tabs/windows, and view-scoped data expiring. I need to write a proper blog post about my thoughts, but for now I'll reference a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098528/jsf-2-0-viewscoped-redirect-navigation-to-target-blank/10108609#10108609) of mine.

Comment: Thanks for your post @BalusC! Always a pleasure to read your answers. As for the options, we're not doing any binding to the specific tags that the link on your blog states, nor are we binding tags directly to a bean. can the problem be caused by using some EL expressions on "rendered" attributes? We do it to adjust the form depending on the case.

Comment: Does the `@ViewScoped` also fail on a basic hello world page with a single submit button wherein the action method returns `null` or `void`?

Comment: Yes, it also loses data. Debugging I've found out that there is a first call with the bean properly setted, then comes a second call with the bean completely clean. I think it gets discarded and then reinstantiated... I've even defined a navigation rule with a redirect directive and include-view-params on true.

Comment: This symptom, in combination with `@ManagedProperty` to fail as well and your favor for `@ConversationScoped`, indicates that you're actually not using JSF `@ManagedBean` at all to manage the beans, but CDI `@Named`. Is this true? The JSF managed bean annotations does **not** work on CDI managed beans.

Comment: Monday morning, fresh mind, and a start from scratch made the trick. This totally worked! Thank you @BalusC, you saved me big time!. Now, I'd like to ask (If you don't mind) two little questions to completely understand the answer. First, What if I want to pass the whole user and not just the id? I have bigger (and lazy-fetching) objects that I wouldn't want to query from database again and second, what's that f:ajax on the commanButton for?. If this deserves a completely new question I'll ask it right away. Thanks again! :).

Comment: You'd need to use commandlink/button instead, yes. But this way you end up with non-bookmarkable and non-searchbot-indexable links to the detail pages.

Comment: I think I'll save myself headaches later by sticking to params and converters. I've been browsing that [massive chunk of knowledge](http://balusc.blogspot.com) that you call your blog and that helped me to fully understand your answer. Congrats for that incredible blog, and thanks for this answer :).