# jsf2 managed beans multiple scoping

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, javabeans

Let's say we have a bean like

```
@ManagedBean(name = "categoriesbean")
@RequestScoped
public class CategoriesBean { 
      Integer id;
      public Integer getId() { return id;}
      public void setId(Integer idarg) { id = idarg;}
      ...
      ...
}
```

and in the same application, elsewhere I have

```
@ManagedBean(name = "categoriesdetailedbean")
@ViewScoped
public class CategoriesDetailedBean extends CategoriesBean { 
      Integer idderived;
      public Integer getIdderived() { return idderived;}
      public void setIdderived(Integer idderivedarg) { idderived = idderivedarg;}
      ...
      ...
}
```

What is the scope of "categoriesdetailedbean", and it's properties (such as scope of Id vs Idderived?).

The reason I ask is, I am seeing some effects which I can't seem to understand very well.

Comment: sorry, i do not criticize your question. i wonder why you need inheritance in managed beans. i recommend you to use POJO classes in managed beans.

Comment: When you define a managed bean, the scope of the bean is determined by what you specify on the class itself, not the base classes. So `categoriesbean` is request scoped and `categoriesdetailedbean` is view scoped. What are the effects you don't understand?

Comment: @erencan: I don't see why managed beans cannot be inherited, especially when i'm re-using a lot of the base object functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class annotations are specific to the class itself and they are discarded when you subclass it. Per saldo, you `CategoriesDetailedBean` has inherited two methods `getId()` and `setId()` and that's all. They do not magically run in a different scope nor hold the values of a different instance.

You're not very clear about the concrete functional requirement, so it's hard to post a suitable answer to what you're *really* trying to do. But if I guess it right, you actually want to access a different managed bean instance from inside a managed bean. If so, then you can use [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) for this. Or perhaps you want a master-detail view and in this case you don't need to inject beans in each other, but better pass the detail ID as GET request parameter and use [`<f:viewParam>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewParam.html) to set it.

#### See also:

- [Elegant handling of attributes without a session bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344256/elegant-handling-of-attributes-without-a-session-bean)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

  - [Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes)
  - [Injecting managed beans in each other](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther)
  - [Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: Thanks for the response @BalusC. Don't think I have enough space to detail my concrete requirements. Maybe I'll post on a blog and link here, so you can guide me.